# Using Old version of mysql connector's security issue

Tags: web-application, mysql, asp.net, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I'm using asp.net 4.0 and MySQL. Last week my hosting firm changed security level of from full to medium. MySQL connector doesn't work correctly anymore. For this reason I'm using old version of ADO.net MySQL connector version number 6.2.5.

Does this situation make my site vulnerable for any attack?

Comment: It makes little sense that they went from full security to medium security and the connector stopped working.  Sounds like you incorrectly determined that the security level is the problem.  If they went medium to full I might agree with you.  In order to know the risk I would check the patch history of the connector see if any security bugs were patched from the version your using to the current version.

Comment: Thans for comment.I'll check the patch history of the MySQL connector.

Comment: @Ramhound What he means is that the application trust level was changed from "full" to "medium".   So, it's basically the opposite of what it sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL Connector 6.2.5 is [the latest version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/connector-net-news-6-2.html). I don't understand why you think it's an older version. Your problems of appending values to your queries and not using prepared statements (if you're doing that) are way more than the version of the connector you are using.

Comment: Latest version of MySQL 6.6.5.I downloaded connector from this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: @dgn - Make sure your only downloading the connector supported by your installation of MySQL.

Comment: Can you explain "_downloading the connector supported by your installation of MySQL_" @Ramhound

Comment: @dgn - Some later versions of the connector might not be supported by the version of MySQL your using.